# How can I put a badge on this cell using Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

This is what I have now:

[image]

I would like to put a badge under the Result column like the image below, instead of getting the full row colored, so that for example GOOD appears inside a green colored badge.

[image]

crud.html

```
    <html>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table data-row-style="rowStyle" class="table table-bordered table-hover thead-dark thead-inverse">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" style="width: 8%" class="text-center">Number</th>
      <th scope="col" style="width: 20%" class="text-center">Name</th>
      <th scope="col" style="width: 61%" class="text-center">Present</th>
      <th scope="col" style="width: 10%" class="text-center">Result</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-center">01</td>
    <td class="text-center">$title01</td>
    <td>$present01</td>
    <td scope="row" class="text-center">GOOD</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-center">02</td>
    <td class="text-center">$title02</td>
    <td>$present02</td>
    <td scope="row" class="text-center">BAD</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-center">03</td>
    <td class="text-center">$title03</td>
    <td>$present03</td>
    <td scope="row" class="text-center">GOOD</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<script>

  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.table tr td').each(function(i, v){
    if(v.textContent === 'GOOD') {
      $(v.parentElement).addClass('table-success');
    } else if(v.textContent === 'BAD') {
      $(v.parentElement).addClass('table-danger');
    }
  })  
})

</script>
<html>
```

code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('crud');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the elements HTML. You can do it like this inside the foreach loop:

```js
if(v.textContent === 'GOOD') {
    $(v).html('<span class="badge badge-success">GOOD</span>');
} else if(v.textContent === 'BAD') {
    $(v).html('<span class="badge badge-danger">BAD</span>');
}
```